# Twitter API error 215

Tags: json, twitter

Today, we discovered one of my clients Twitter feeds became broken.

I have tried switching to using the new API 1.1, but get the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Even using their own example generates the same response:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2
```

I am referencing the following documentation.

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline
```

Any idea what's up with this?

Thanks,
Mikey

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807221/get-twitter-friends-list/54838712#54838712

Answer (score 50, accepted):

So, it seems Twitter's latest API 1.1 does **not allow** access without authentication - even for data that is seemingly public...like the latest 3 tweets from a timeline.

The best article I have found on this (which gives a great solution) for read-access can be found here:

http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

I have followed the steps in the article above and can confirm it works great.

An interesting point to note, is that now, because you have to use *access tokens* and *secret keys*; all requests must be made with a server-side script. Prior to this I was using jQuery to make an AJAX request on Twitters JSON API directly. Now, you must AJAX request a dynamic script on your own website, if you wish to go down a Javascript route.

Comment: can I get a .json since front-end using jquery or angular.js for example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446255/get-web-service-from-api-twitter-1-1

Answer (score 9):

Your example doesn't state whether you are authenticating, so I will assume you are not.

**All** methods in API 1.1 require authentication via OAuth.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a

Unauthenticated access is discontinued permanently.

Comment: I simply want to pull in the latest 3 tweets to the page; retrieving only information that's already public. This was fine before, but now requires authentication? There is / will be, no user process to this. It's just a simple "latest tweets" box.

Comment: Yep. Same problem for thousands of others with broken apps. They dislike tweets being displayed by third parties and want to force you into using their official [embedded timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines).

Comment: Sorry, Page doesn't exists.

Comment: you could look at  https://www.dataneb.com/post/how-to-make-calls-to-twitter-apis-using-postman-client  to make a request using OAuth1.0 with the following