# Still possible to use jquery to get tweets falling under #hashtag using Twitter API 1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

I'm reading the documentation for using the Twitter Search API. I want to return a really simple list aka https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40hashtag falling under a single hashtag, but every time I try I get back this error in the browser:

{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

I'm confused about whether it's still possible to get back JSON and use it with $.ajax or $.getJSON in version 1.1 of the Twitter API.

Comment: EDIT: I just found this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143985/twitter-api-error-215

Comment: In other words, can someone confirm that now it's not so easy to create twitter streams using AJAX/jQuery from publicly available data anymore? Now you need to "AJAX request a dynamic script on your own website".