# Twitter error code 215: Bad Authentication Data

Tags: php, api, authentication, twitter

I want to create a web application which will allow users to input a Twitter Page URL or Twitter name, and I will return some page information/statistics of that page.

All the data I retrieve will be public, hence I do not need require any user authentication.

I am trying to execute the following query,

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterapi

which should return some type of information according to the Twitter Reference https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show.

However when I execute the URL in my browser, I get the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Could anyone provide any explanation or alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter does not allow gathering of information without OAuth:

[Twitter API error 215](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143985/twitter-api-error-215)

Comment: So It will work with Hybridauth right?