# Get post form twitter public profile in java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to review twitter public profile using twitter4J.
I tried the examples on twitter4j git location but it did not worked.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Paging;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class TwitterTimeLine {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    int pageno = 1;
    String user = "google";
    List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>();

    while (true) {

      try {

        int size = statuses.size(); 
        Paging page = new Paging(pageno++, 100);
        statuses.addAll(twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page));
        if (statuses.size() == size)
          break;
      }
      catch(TwitterException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Total: "+statuses.size());
}
}
```

But it always gives me error

```
400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.
message - Bad Authentication data.
code - 215

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=4be80492 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0a6306df
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[4be80492-0a6306df], statusCode=400, message=Bad Authentication data., code=215, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1786)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getUserTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:131)
    at com.twitter.ibeat.iBeatTwitter.TwitterTimeLine.main(TwitterTimeLine.java:33)
400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.
message - Bad Authentication data.
code - 215
```

Could you please help me to get this working.
Regards
Virendra Agarwal

Comment: All methods in Twitter API 1.1 require authentication via OAuth. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143985/twitter-api-error-215

Comment: Thanks @BalwinderSingh i created OAuth token and it is working.  Could you please tell em how can i get tweet for today only using the same code.  Also i need to get multiple users tweets here so could you please suggest me code changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved using oAuth token and Query API from twitter4J.