# Hitting Twitter Api with Postman

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, postman

I am trying to hit twitter status update post api with Postman but even after choosing OAuth1.0 I am getting:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 215,
            "message": "Bad Authentication data."
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not getting what should be done so I can post the data using POSTMAN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17143985/1456997

Comment: Thanks, but I went through that link already and I didn't found that answering my question.