# how can i get twitter lists information (subscribe information)

Tags: r, list, twitter, subscribe

i saw some example code for finding members of list.
so i changed it slightly and converged for fit to me, however it doesn't work

```
screen_name <-"Newsminster" 
api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/list.json?","screen_name=", screen_name)

url.get=GET(api.url)
url.content=content(url.get, as="text")
```

output :

> url.content
>   [1] "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":215,\"message\":\"Bad Authentication data.\"}]}"

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Twitter's latest API 1.1 does not allow access without authentication

The article can be found here:

http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

*check this answer as well*

Reference

[Twitter API error 215](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143985/twitter-api-error-215)