# Issue while trying to extract request token using Twitter API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**Error Message**

> Client error: `POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`
> resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

**Extract Token from Twitter**

```
$method = "POST";
$endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
$authorizationParams = [
    "oauth_callback" => "url, this matches with Callback URI of api info",
    "oauth_consumer_key" => "my api key",
    "oauth_nonce" => md5(microtime(). mt_rand()),
    "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
    "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
    "oauth_version" => "1.0"
];

$authorizationParams["oauth_signature"] = $this->GetSignature($method, $endpoint, $authorizationParams);
$authorizationString = $this->getAuthorizationString($authorizationParams);
```

**Post Request to Twitter**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $endpoint, [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        "Authorization: OAuth " . $authorizationString
    ]
]);
$result = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

**Signature generation**

```
private function GetSignature($method, $endpoint, $authorizationParams) {
    $twitter_conf = \Config::get('twitter');
    uksort($authorizationParams, "strcmp");
    foreach($authorizationParams as $key => $value) {
        $authorizationParams[$key] = rawurlencode($key) . "=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    
    $signatureBase = [
        rawurlencode($method),
        rawurlencode($endpoint),
        rawurlencode(implode("&", $authorizationParams)),
    ];
    
    $signatureBaseString = implode("&", $signatureBase);
    $signatureKey = [
        rawurlencode($twitter_conf["secret"]),
        ""
    ];
    
    $signatureKeyString = implode("&", $signatureKey);
    
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $signatureBaseString, $signatureKeyString, true));
}
```

**Convert array to string**

```
private function getAuthorizationString($authorizationParams) {
    $authorizationString = "";
    $count = 0;
    foreach($authorizationParams as $key => $value) {
        $authorizationString .= $count == 0 ? "" : ",";
        $authorizationString .= rawurlencode($key) . '="' . rawurlencode($value) . '"';
        $count++;
    }
    return $authorizationString;
}
```

Comment: It says *Bad Authentication data.* did you check auth?. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143985/twitter-api-error-215

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is about request token only. I saw that you have suggested user timeline. I saw that link. but did not help –

Comment: Why don't you use a [Twitter client](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/v2#php)?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to passing the "oauth_callback" value as part of the header.  According to https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/request_token, "oauth_callback" should be passed as a query string as part of the endpoint URL.

Try something like this instead:

```
$CALLBACK_URL = urlencode( "url, this matches with Callback URI of api info" );
$method = "POST";
$endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=$CALLBACK_URL";
$authorizationParams = [
    "oauth_consumer_key" => "my api key",
    "oauth_nonce" => md5(microtime(). mt_rand()),
    "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
    "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
    "oauth_version" => "1.0"
];

$authorizationParams["oauth_signature"] = $this->GetSignature($method, $endpoint, $authorizationParams);
$authorizationString = $this->getAuthorizationString($authorizationParams);
```

When modifying the request to the above, make sure you modify the signature.  Here's an example of how my application signs requests.  Take note of the fact that it's extracting the endpoint URL's query string and encoding it into the signature.  Your signing method does not do this and will likely return a bad signature.  Also note, that the endpoint URL has been stripped of the same query portion in the base string to be used for generating the hash.

```
function generateSignature( $method, $url, $params = [] ) {
        $parts = parse_url( $url );

        // We need to normalize the endpoint URL
        $scheme = isset( $parts['scheme'] ) ? $parts['scheme'] : 'http';
        $host = isset( $parts['host'] ) ? $parts['host'] : '';
        $port = isset( $parts['port'] ) ? $parts['port'] : ( $scheme == 'https' ? '443' : '80' );
        $path = isset( $parts['path'] ) ? $parts['path'] : '';
        if( ( $scheme == 'https' && $port != '443' ) ||
            ( $scheme == 'http' && $port != '80' )
        ) {
            // Only include the port if it's not the default
            $host = "$host:$port";
        }

        // Also the parameters
        $pairs = [];
        parse_str( isset( $parts['query'] ) ? $parts['query'] : '', $query );
        $query += $params;
        unset( $query['oauth_signature'] );
        if( $query ) {
            $query = array_combine(
            // rawurlencode follows RFC 3986 since PHP 5.3
                array_map( 'rawurlencode', array_keys( $query ) ),
                array_map( 'rawurlencode', array_values( $query ) )
            );
            ksort( $query, SORT_STRING );
            foreach( $query as $k => $v ) {
                $pairs[] = "$k=$v";
            }
        }

        $toSign = rawurlencode( strtoupper( $method ) ) . '&' .
                  rawurlencode( "$scheme://$host$path" ) . '&' .
                  rawurlencode( join( '&', $pairs ) );
        $key = rawurlencode( CONSUMERSECRET ) . '&' .
               rawurlencode( ( isset( ACCESSTOKENSECRET ) ?
                   ACCESSTOKENSECRET :
                   ( isset( REQUESTTOKENSECRET ) ? REQUESTTOKENSECRET :
                       "" ) )
               );

        return base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha1', $toSign, $key, true ) );
    }
```